# Overlapping the same element

Tags: css, position, react-native

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: Overlapping circles]

I am stuck on trying to solve this issue. Should I define different styles based on the position in the list or would it be possible to solve this by having the same style for all of the items and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a class of elements, that has a specified size, `display: inline-block` to display in a row and a negative right margin to overlap.

The following is a plain HTML/CSS example to solve your issue. Of course you will have to port that into your React Native application.

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 15px #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: React-native (see question's tags) doesn't support standart web html and css.

Comment: @AlexBelets The OP gave no code, so I decided to give a short simple example of how the basic styles (which the OP explicitly asked for) could look like. As the answer got accepted, I assume, that's all that was needed here.
But thanks anyway for your comment, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (not the best way) would be something like this.
If you use a preprocessor you could write this DRYer.

```css
ul {
  padding: 20px 0;
  list-style: none;
  clear: both;
 }
 
 .item {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .item img { 
   border-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
 }
 
.item:nth-child(1) img {
  background: #aaa;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
.item:nth-child(2) img {
  background: #bbb;
   left: -20px;
 }
 
.item:nth-child(3) img {
  background: #ccc;
   left: -40px;
 }
 
.item:nth-child(4) img {
  background: #ddd;
  left: -60px;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item"><img src="" width="50" height="50"></li>  
  <li class="item"><img src="" width="50" height="50"></li>  
  <li class="item"><img src="" width="50" height="50"></li>
  <li class="item"><img src="" width="50" height="50"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same styles for all elements because when we have row with flex-direction: 'row', first element will be placed at start of row.

Do not use negative margins! It possible will not work on IOS.

Next, you should remember that in react-native every next element will be over the previous one. So the only thing you should do is image positioning inside small block.

Comment: Why you downvote my answer? Did you see tags 'react-native' and 'react-native-stylesheet'? It's not about web. It's all about mobile development. Answers with html snippets are incorrect!